# Problems running SDK 3 iPhone App on IOS4

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I have made an iPhone app  building with SDK 3, expecting it to run on all platfroms of IOS 3 and up.

My app uses location services, and in iPhone 4 IOS one can shut down location services for a specific app.  Doing so causes my app to hang indefinitely.  I handle the case where location services are disabled in general, but not per app.  I couldn't because it is not supported in SDK 3

How can I have my app support IOS4 in this aspect (and unforeseen others) while maintaining compatability with SDK 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's Location Awareness Programming Guide

> #### Determining Whether Location Services Are Available
>
> Every iOS-based device is capable of supporting location services in some form but there are still situations where location services may not be available:
>
> - The user can disable location services in the Settings application.
> - The user can deny location services for a specific application.
> - The device might be in Airplane mode and unable to power up the necessary hardware.
>
> For these reasons, it is recommended that you always call the locationServicesEnabled class method of CLLocationManager before attempting to start either the standard or significant-change location services. (In iOS 3.x and earlier, check the value of the locationServicesEnabled property instead.)

It specifically mentions "iOS 3.x and earlier" so I think it should work. Hope it helps.Blockquoted